# RabbitMQ: Move messages to another queue on acknowledgement received

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a setup with two queues (no exchanges), let's say queue A and queue B.

One parser puts messages on queue A, that are consumed by ElasticSearch RabbitMQ river.

What I want now is to move messages from queue A to queue B when the ES river sends an ack to the queue A, so that I can do other processing in the ack'd messages, being sure that ES already has processed them.

Is there any way in RabbitMQ to do this? If not, is there any other setup that can guarantee me that a message is only in queue B after being processed by ES?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported by either AMQP or the [rabbitmq extensions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/extensions.html).

1. You could drop the river and let your consumer also publish to elasticsearch.
2. Since a normal behavior is that the queues are empty you can just perform a few retries of reading the entries from elasticsearch (with exponential backoff), so even if the elasticsearch loses the initial race it will backoff a bit and you can then perform the task. This might require tuning the prefetch_size/count in your clients.

Comment: Hum, some comments:  
  
1. My only consumer is the river, so if I drop it I will not have any messages being indexed into elasticsearch  
  
2. What do you mean by "the queues are empty"? Right now, my river indexes faster than the parser output to the query, on my testing environment. But on production this will certainly not be the case since the parser output will be much, much higher.

Comment: I was thinking about having a second consumer for the same messages doing the work what the "river" is currently doing as well as the other post-processing steps you need.